# How can I use regex to replace numbers in my regular expressions inside notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have the following:

```
<d:RowKey>XXXX004K<
```

replace with

```
<d:RowKey>050505004K<
```

and

```
RowKey='XXXX004K'
```

replace with

```
RowKey='0505050004K'
```

Can someone help me with the regular expression syntax for these. The value of "X" in the above can be any number.

Sorry but I have never used regex before. I just need some way to do this inside notepad++ where it gives me an option of regex for a search string.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java or C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried with a simple string

```
string pattern = @"\d{4}004K";
string search = "<d:RowKey>8989004K<";
var result = Regex.Replace(search, pattern, "050505004K");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    Find What: ([>'])[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
    Replace With : \1050505
```

Assuming 05050504K< there is a typo in here